# Large Data Processing and Management in MongoDB using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to do CRUD operations on MongoDB of a very large size around 20GB data and there can be multiple such versions of data. Can anyone guide me on how to handle such high data for the CRUD operations and maintaining the previous versions of the data in MongoDB?

I am using NodeJS as backend and I can also use any other database if required.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb is a reliable database, I am using it to processes 10-11 billions of data every single day nodejs should also be fine as long as you are handling the files in streams of data.

Things you should do to Optimize:
Indexing - this will be the biggest part, if you want faster queries you better look into indexing in mongodb, every single document needs to be indexed according to your query, else you are going to have a tough time dealing with queries.
Sharding and Replication - this will help you organise the data and increases the query speed, replication would allow you to have your reads and writes separated(there are cons for replication you can read about that in the mongodb documentation).

This are the main things you need to consider, there are a lot but this should get you started...;) need any help please do let me know.

Comment: I will start with the direction you provided and I will let you know about the results